# Problem in installing wifi driver rtl8188eus

Tags: drivers, wireless

I tried to install RTL8188EUS by performing a solution provided from this site, but it tells "Error! Could not find module source directory. Directory: /usr/src/.-rtl8188eu does not exist."

Comment: More details are needed. It looks like you made a typo in some command.

Comment: Just remove the .- from the dkms install command it should be `sudo dkms install rtl8188eu/{version}`

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I'll try that at once